# Flash builder 4.6 , php and mysqli database is not updated with data but returns insert_id. database shows only null values

Tags: php, mysqli

The EmployeeServiceg class connects to the mysql database.
i can retrieve data from the db but have difficulty with the insert statement as the auto_id returns the new persid but there are only null values in all the other db columns.

thanks in advance.

```
class EmployeeServiceg{ 
  var $username = "root"; 
  var $password = ""; 
  var $server = "localhost"; 
  var $port = "3306"; 
  var $databasename = "hg"; 
  var $tablename = "employees"; 

  var $connection; 
  public function __construct() { 
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect( 
                   $this->server,  
                   $this->username,  
                   $this->password, 
                   $this->databasename, 
                   $this->port 
                   ); 

   $this->throwExceptionOnError($this->connection); 
  }  

  public function createEmployee($item) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
        "INSERT INTO employees (name, surname, title, cellphone, email,
                streetno, street, city, employeeno, idno) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();


    mysqli_bind_param($stmt,'ssssssssss', $row->name, $row->surname, $row->title,
        $row->cellphone, $row->email, $row->streetno, $row->street, $row->city,
        $row->employeeno, $row->idno);


    $this->throwExceptionOnError();


    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();


    $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);


    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $autoid;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is contained is the $row var ? It should be $item no ?